# TFS MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0 Documents and Reports nodes are missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates, tfs

Reading about TFS' MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0 template ([for example here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2011/02/10/tfs-2010-msf-agile-vs-visual-studio-scrum-1-0-smackdown-planning-w-agile-part-ii.aspx)) I can see nice **Documents** and **Reports** installed by default:

[image]

but after I installed this template myself I can see no such nodes:

[image]

**What should I do to see (or install) them?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The administrator either did a basic wizard install or they did advanced and opted out share point and reporting integration.  The basic wizard is actually just a wizard and the result is equivalent to advanced with opted-out.  So in that sense, there really is no such thing as a basic installation - just a basics wizard.  After the wizard there's no way of telling how you got where you got.

If TFS is installed on a client OS, you will not be able to add Sharepoint and Reporting integration.  If you are on a server OS you can go into the admin console on the server, go to the share point and reporting nodes and configure them.

At that point, you will have to install SharePoint and Reporting services.  But, if you download TFS Dev11 CTP (just came out at build conference), the SharePoint integration wizard will take it E2E even after the fact.  It will detect what's missing and just do it.  However, Dev11 CTP is not go live - at Beta, you can upgrade to it.

Here's a document on adding share point to an existing TFS deployment:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462861

After you configure SharePoint and Reporting services, you will need to enable them for existing projects:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggboer/archive/2010/02/24/creating-sharepoint-portals-reports-and-upgrading-reports-for-an-existing-team-project.aspx

For reporting, go to the reporting node in the admin console.  There's a link in there to configure.  Point to your sql and analysis services and it should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: Thank you for useful info, +1. Yes, I've made my install on a client OS.

Comment: OK - In Dev10 client OS support was added but it's scoped to the core parts of TFS.  The share point and reporting services are not available on a client OS.  *IF* you really want it, you can back up your DBs, move them to a server OS, install TFS, and then run through the ATOnly wizard.  After that, do what is discussed above.

Comment: Just to sum up and make sure I understand everything right: in case of TFS is installed on a client OS, there could be no reports available in TFS at all?

Comment: Correct - the reporting features are not available on a client OS - just the core services.

Answer (score 2):

You have not made a full Team Foundation Server installation. Follow this guide: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24337
This installation guide gives lots of important information regarding installation of a Team Foundation Server. Including important information on the SQL Server setup. Reporting Server is used for reports. And documents are stored in a Sharepoint product.

I think you have made a *Basic Installation*.

The missing documents and reports, has nothing to do with the process template you are using (MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0).

Comment: Thanks, Morten, +1. In fact, I've made a custom install, but, indeed, without installing Sharepoint and Reporting server. Which, I think, is something similar to "Basic Installation".

Comment: It's the same thing.  Basics is just a wizard and same as advanced with defaults minus SP & Reporting

Comment: ... also, on client OS, SP & RS are disabled so for client OS, advanced with defaults == basics.  Adv just becomes of way of doing things like specifying a domain acct, change port etc...